# disable android back button only on certian pages

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm developing a jquery mobile app which contain many pages on one document. for example there pages #welcome,#about etc. and i want to only disable the back button on the android phone only when #about page is active. I have this script that disables the button through the application

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false );}
```

Comment: you should also place jquery mobile tag

Answer (score 0):

In jquery mobile, $.mobile.activePage.attr('id') will return the id value of the current active page.So in your case if the current active page's id value not equals **'about'**,you need the default back button behaviour.For that you can give the code as given below.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {         
    //check if the current page is not an about page
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id')!=="about")
     {
      //In all other pages except 'about',the normal back button behaviour is exhibited
      window.history.back();
     }
}, false );}
```

When you press the back button on android phone ,the above code checks if the current page is not an about page,if the condition is true,the default back button behaviour is given by the code  **window.history.back()**;